# PHP's unsigned integer on 32 bit and 64 bit platform

Tags: integer, unsigned

Here is the code:

```
echo sprintf('%u',-123);
```

And this is the output on 32 bit platform:

```
4294967173
```

but on 64 bit:

```
18446744073709551493
```

How to make it the same ?Say,the int(10) unsigned

Comment: Depends what output you actually *want*. I could make it the same by doing `echo "foo"` on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo sprintf('-%u',abs(-123));
```

or

```
$n = -123;
echo sprintf("%s%u", $n < 0 ? "-":"", abs($n));
```

Though if you actually want to see the two's complement unsigned value of a negative number restricted to 32 bits just do:

```
echo sprintf("%u", $n & 0xffffffff);
```

And that will print `4294967173` on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872424/unsigned-int-to-signed-in-php) for some ideas - in a nutshell, you can check the value of the PHP_INT_SIZE constant to perform different processing on a 64bit platform.