# Can mysqli binding unsigned int?

Tags: php, mysqli

when i do mysqli update using prepare and then bind param like:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $svr_id, $group_id)
```

here comes the problem:
In my database, svr_id was defined as unsigned int, but when binding, it is specified by int.
when

> $svr_id>0x1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

, it seems that it was considered to be a negative num, and the update command failed.
but i can't find a param to make it unsigned int in function `bind_param()`; 
Is anyone can help to solve this?

Comment: Why not to post *complete reproduceable* code, so everyone could run and confirm that it is indeed the case, not some typo in your own code?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/872484/789186

Comment: Bug #35518 mysqli bind_param() incorrectly handles unsigned int https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35518

Comment: @Damodaran, it's not a bug

Answer (score 0):

Your number greater that MAX_INT. When you trying to bind php converts it to integer.

Solution: bind values as strings.