# Converting unsigned short to integer in PHP

Tags: php, port, ip-address, type-conversion

I am trying to utilize the following php function:

```
socket_bind ( resource $socket , string $address [, int $port = 0 ] )
```

and I have the 3 fields ($socket, $address, $port) available to me but they've been sent to me in a different format. There exists documentation that details how the sender (I am the receiver in this case) will  be sending me the address/port:

> The address, **port**, and size should be sent as ASCII
>   representations of the decimal integer formed by converting the values
>   to host byte order and treating them as an unsigned long, **unsigned
>   short**, and unsigned long respectively.

I need to convert the port back from the unsigned short to an integer so that I can use socket_bind. Is there an easy way to do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: PHP does not support unsigned integers

 : http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php

Comment: See the answer selected in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872424/unsigned-int-to-signed-in-php. The same methodology should work for your use case.